# rendering plt.savefig() to HTML page with flask

Tags: python, html, flask

I want to render an html page that contains an image, produced by some matplotlib functions. So I figured that I have to:

1. perform all the nescessary matplotlib plotting
2. output it to an PNG  file in /static folder
3. render the resulting PNG file to html

So in my main.py I do:

```
plt.imshow(a)
for i in range(len(obj)):
    x = obj[i][u'faceRectangle'][u'left']
    y = obj[i][u'faceRectangle'][u'top']
    w = obj[i][u'faceRectangle'][u'width']
    h = obj[i][u'faceRectangle'][u'height']
    plt.plot([x,x+w],[y,y], color='r')
    plt.plot([x,x+w],[y+h,y+h], color='r')
    plt.plot([x,x],[y,y+h], color='r')
    plt.plot([x+w,x+w],[y,y+h], color='r')
plt.savefig('static/1.png')
plt.clf()
```

That produces a "1.PNG" file in my /static folder like this one:

[image]

Than I renderan html template that has the following line:

```
<img src="{{url_for('static', filename='1.png')}}" >
```

This code works perfectly and the image gets included in the resulting html page.
Than something strangehappens, when I run the same code with another image it works well in the sence that it replaces the static/1.png file with the new one, but it keeps displaying the first image in the html page. Even thow there is no such image in the static/ folder anymore.

If it is the browser caching the file how can I avoid the same to happen to other users, do I need to make random filenames somehow?

Comment: Assuming that the file is regenerated with the same name.  I’m curious if your browser is caching that image.

Comment: How can I go about it? The other peoples browsers will also cache is. Do I need to make random filenames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider tacking a cache-busting nonce on to the end of the URL:

```
>>> '1.png?%d' % time.time()
'1.png?1505929617'
```

Or use e.g. `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 60`